# 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request in symfony 5

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I hosting my Symfony 5 application in shared hosting Cpanel. When i use .htaccess file then show below error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@famousmartbd.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

.htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/public/index.php [L]
</IfModule><IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /public/index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

How to solve this error. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misconfiguration. Try to remove this `<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>`